# Why doesn't the hyperlink work?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, abstract, hyperlink

When I click on the hyperlink in the table of contents it does not direct me to the "Resumo" section. How do I fix this?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
% Centrar verticalmente
\begin{center} %%%
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-9cm} %diminuir bordas
    
    \begin{center} \large \textbf{Resumo} \end{center} %titulo
   \lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}
\end{center} %%%
%
\vspace*{\fill}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Resumo} %add indice
\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: You want the `\addcontentsline` inside the `center` environment and `\phantomsection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `\addcontentsline` in a different place and also `\phantomsection` to set the anchor.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
% Centrar verticalmente
\begin{center} %%%
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Resumo} %add indice
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-9cm} %diminuir bordas

    \begin{center} \large \textbf{Resumo} \end{center} %titulo
   \lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}
\end{center} %%%
%
\vspace*{\fill}
\newpage

\end{document}
```